# Is there any way I can execute a JavaScript export statement with some delay?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I'm building a tool using React and Redux. I'm using whatwg-fetch to make a server side call and fetch some data. And I have a reducer, which will have its store created in a callback, after the data has been successfully fetched. Here is my code:

```
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import 'whatwg-fetch';

let notificationCardList = [],
    initialState,
    store;

const fetchData = () => {
  fetch('http://localhost:6767/file/data.json')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseData) => {
      notificationCardList = Object.keys(responseData).map(key => responseData[key]);
    })
    .then(initializeReducer);
}

const initializeReducer = () => {
  initialState = {
    notifCardsToBeDisplayed: notificationCardList,
    notifCardToBeDisplayed: null
  };

  function manipulateNotificationCards (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'OPEN_CARD':
        return Object.assign(state, {
          notifCardsToBeDisplayed: null,
          notifCardToBeDisplayed: action.card,
          notifCardsContainerPreviousState: action.notifCardsContainerCurrentState
        });
      case 'DISPLAY_CARD_LIST':
        return Object.assign(state, {
          notifCardsToBeDisplayed: action.cards,
          notifCardToBeDisplayed: null
        });
      default:
        return state;
    }
  }

  store = createStore(manipulateNotificationCards);
}

fetchData();  

export {store, notificationCardList};
```

But since the store is being created as a part of the callback, due to asynchronous behaviour, the export statement is probably getting executed before the createStore() statement, hence I'm effectively exporting an undefined 'store'. I thought about placing the export statement in the callback as well, but then again, export statements can only be there at the top level. I also tried using setTimeout(), but that didn't work either. Is there any way I can export 'store' after it's created?

Answer (score 3):

The usual scheme for handling asynchronous initialization is to use a module constructor function that gets the desired exported value and that module constructor either returns a promise or takes a callback and the asynchronous exported value is only available via that mechanism.  This is because the async operation takes an indeterminate amount of time so the only way a caller can reliably use it is to wait for it to be available via some sort of promise or callback.

A cached promise is a very clean way of doing this.  The module initialization stores a promise that will resolve with the desired async value.  A module method fetches the promise and the caller then uses `.then()` on the promise.  If the module has not yet finished fetching the async value, then the promise will not call the `.then()` handler until the value is ready.  If the value is already available, then the `.then()` handler will be called immediately.  In either case, the caller just fetches the promise, adds a `.then()` handler and then acts on the value in the `.then()` callback.

Some examples of these methods here: [How to async require in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34962075/how-to-async-require-in-nodejs/34962383#34962383)

Comment: The problem is that I can't place the export statement in a callback, as JavaScript doesn't allow that. So my 'store' will always be exported before it's assigned a value. My question is whether I can somehow execute the export statement with a delay, so as to provide time for the callback to be executed.

Comment: @RajarshiChakrabarti - I didn't say to put the export in a callback.  I said to export a promise or export a function that takes a callback.  You cannot do the export statement with a delay.  You have to restructure your code so that the caller waits for the value to be ready.  And, you can either have the caller pass a callback into a module function and that callback will be called when the value is ready or you have the caller fetch a promise that they can attach a `.then()` handler to that will be called when the value is ready.

Comment: @RajarshiChakrabarti - Examples here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34962075/how-to-async-require-in-nodejs/34962383#34962383

Comment: @coder - It is not appropriate to be asking here for help on a completely unrelated question. That is not cool on stack overflow.

Comment: @jfriend00: I am really sorry for this, I m so much confused that I m not able to think what should I do. Any suggestion also would be very much appreciated.