# Optimizing Firebase cloud functions structure in node.js

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

In [this official Firebase example](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/organize-cloud-functions-for-max-cold-start-performance-and-readability-with-typescript-and-9261ee8450f0) it's described how to structure cloud functions to minimize cold start times.

The main idea seems to be the following in the index.ts file:

```
export const httpFn =
functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
    await (await import('./fn/httpFn')).default(request, response)
})
```

In other words using await( await import()). This example is however in typescript. How would this look in node.js? I've found some examples. Eg. [this one](https://github.com/debelopumento/firebase-cloud-functions-boilerplate).

In there the index.js file has:

```
exports.helloWorld = require('./hello-world').helloWorld
```

And the individual function files look like:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    const output = {
        di: 'is cool',
    }
    response.send(output)
})
```

Is this the optimal method to minimize cold start time in node.js? Given I can't use "await import". Will this structure only load the necessary dependencies for each individual function? Or will it still load all dependencies across all required (imported) files?

Answer (score 1):

That blog post you're referring to is not an "official sample".  It's a description of my own personal thoughts and opinions.

What you're showing here is not equivalent to what's shown in the blog post.  If you want a pure JavaScript implementation of TypeScript's async import, you will have to write code to mimic that.  `require()` is **not** asynchronous and doesn't achieve the same thing.

I suggest reading other questions on Stack Overflow on this topic:

- [Node.js - asynchronous module loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20315434/node-js-asynchronous-module-loading)
- [How to async require in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34962075/how-to-async-require-in-nodejs)